# What is the proper set of R8 rules needed in "android.enableR8.fullMode=true" for a Google API Drive, Sheets, and Calendar Android application?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

In previous version of an Android app this R8 rule was sufficient to keep the needed GSON related parts from the Google API libraries:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}
```

After updating libraries and Android Studio (Eel to Flamingo) the app regressed to problems seen only in the shrunk version, and only at runtime. This was caused by R8 running by default with `android.enableR8.fullMode=true`.

It was figured out that the additional rules:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonError {
    public *;
}

-keepclassmembers class com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonError$* {
    public *; 
}

-keepclassmembers public class  com.google.api.services.drive.model.* extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {
    public *;
}

-keepclassmembers public class  com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.* extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {
    public *;
}

-keepclassmembers public class  com.google.api.services.calendar.model.* extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {
    public *;
}
```

would solve the new issues in the example case. The pattern is clear: the `model` package classes must be explicitly retained.

This was a very unsatisfying experience because it required testing to find the problems, and that future changes in R8 and maybe the libraries would invalidate the empirically determined rules.

It seems that the Google API libraries should come with the required R8 (i.e. Proguard) rules that were established by knowledge of the libraries, and a very comprehensive testing suite done by the developers.

My question is, does this resource exist?

Comment: You probably can narrow the rules to only non transient fields - `!transient public <field>` in stead of `public *`,

You mention _updating libraries and Android Studio_ caused this. Was it both in combination or did this also happen with only one of these updates in isolation. You might also open an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788 with more information on the runtime crash - at least this could lead to updating https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/main/compatibility-faq.md.

Comment: The `!transient public <fields>` breaks the fix. Limiting to `<methods>` is okay with limited testing...

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no centralized resource that provides a complete set of Proguard rules for all Google API libraries. Sometimes they write in a documentation of a specific library which rules you need to use (for instance, in [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard)).

But in the most cases, it's required to test the release version of a build in order to try to get some crashes.

Comment: Just learned that my added rules were not enough. An uncommon error condition sent the code down a pathway that referenced a shrunken class. Testing every possible pathway is a very demanding requirement!!

Answer (score 0):

Libraries can and do contain R8/Proguard rules. For example:

```
google-api-client/META-INF/proguard/google-api-client.pro
```

contains the rule:

```
-keep public class com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils
```

Code can be included in a library to retain content. There are many "hacks"
like the following:

```
static {
    // hack to force ProGuard to consider BandedRange used, since otherwise it would be stripped out
    // see https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues/543
    com.google.api.client.util.Data.nullOf(BandedRange.class);
}
```

An Android library can include the following:

```
    defaultConfig {
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }
```

which embeds the rules file in the libraries '.aar' and these keep rules are
applied by all clients of the library unless explicitly not include with:

```
        release {
            optimization {
                keepRules {
                    ignoreExternalDependencies 'com.hanafey.android.gapiu:gapiu'
                }
            }
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release_testing
        }
```

One problem with library specified keep rules is that they can retain more
than is needed in a specific case. This is particularly true for a large
library that the client only uses a part of. The library's 'consumer-rules.
pro' cannot account for what the client actually needs. The keep rules do
not allow conditional statements like "if function X is used then because X
uses reflection to access other parts of the library,  a retained "X"
must also drag with it "P", "Q", and "R".